# How do I increment the number in a file I create each time a new file is create?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, c#-4.0, increment, edi

I am creating a file conversion console app to change xml files generated by an shopping cart export to x12 850 EDI txt files using Visual C#. I need one number in the txt file being created to increment by one, then store this new number in the app itself so that the next file converted increments one past the last file created, and for this to continue with each additional file converted. What is the past way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Tyrel

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having difficulties with? Does this number have to keep incrementing across restarts? Across servers?

Comment: I have considered using int and the increment method, but do not know how to retain the last number incremented to. I have tried incrementing a numerical string, but I cannot modify the string to hold the new variable. Yes the number needs to keep incrementing across restarts. I plan on calling this app with task scheduler to batch convert files. As for across servers, I do not fully understand the question. My apologies.

Comment: Basically asking if you have the application running on more than one computer and if so does this number need to keep incrementing between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on a lot of things.

The main issue is going to be one of efficiency.

The file system watcher [MSDN HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) will get you the events of the files being created, but then you will have to deal with all of the *potential* scenarios, like someone putting in files another type in the directory, multiple files at once, etc.

If I were designing such a thing I would consider a multithreaded app and some queueing.

Part#2...

It will not modify the integer, it will notify you when the files are created / deleted etc. Keeping count of those events will allow you to keep track of the files themselves. Persisting the setting would require something external to the running application such as a registry key or disk file. By queuing events from the file system watcher, you can control access to that persisted file in a clean organized manner ensuring that it always corresponds to the operation at hand, not just a file creation or deletion event.

Essentially every time the app loads get the last value from the file, as an operation process increment / decrement the value that is in memory and write it back out to that file.
The value would be an integer in memory and simply incremented or decremented with a ++ or – as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy3d35h8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: It seems a little eager to suggest the OP should `consider a multithreaded app and some queueing` without more details of what they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have edited the original question to better reflect the purpose of the app.

Comment: Seems completely reasonable when you consider what could happen. 
By using a multithreaded queue the program can do things like account for files being added in bulk, removed while others are still processing, provide user feedback while operations are in progress (pending operations vs current), one operation has write access to the file locked when another tries to update it, the list goes on.
 The question comes down to do you want a solution or a fix.
Writing an application that covers the bases from the start saves time and coding costs.

Comment: While people putting files of a different type are not a concern, as the xml files will be generated by a shopping cart application and ftp'ed in, the possibilty of multiple files at once is certainly a scenario I need to account for. However, do not understand how file system watcher will modify the integer that I need incremented in the file I am created. Could you please clarify?

Comment: too large for comment, see second answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This conversation not only helped answer the immediate question, but addressed the issues that I knew I would need to address next.

Comment: To continue this discussion, could I not use a foreach loop to process the files in the directory(ie. foreach .xml file in C:\foo covert/delete)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a single instance of the program and that the value needs to be kept across restarts of the application (and possibly the computer):

- Use a file to store the current value of your counter
- When the application starts, read this value
- Increment the value in memory as needed (in an `int` or whatever you use)
- Before the application exits, overwrite the file with the new value

Comment: Thank you for your help. This will accomplish what I want. I was hoping to keep it all within the code of the app, but that may not be possible.